# Запятая, или тире, или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

`От одежды на вас до телефона у вас в руках (?) любая вещь требует работы дизайнера.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> От одежды на вас до телефона у вас в руках — любая вещь требует работы дизайнера.

> От одежды на вас до телефона у вас в руках — словом, любая вещь требует работы дизайнера.

Первая часть предложения — перечисление, вторая — обобщающее словчонко. Я понимаю, что это трудно назвать перечислением, но всё же обощающее слово неоспоримо, так что тирешка оправдана будет всегда. Это мини-перечисление.

Comment: Именительный темы? А такой вариант есть в ПАС?  Или какой у вас источник?  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

Comment: Правильнее, думаю, назвать это перечислением с обобщающим словом.

Comment: Я ещё только учусь, мэм. Я — это ещё мини-коток. (Но мини-коток, наполненный потенциала! Не правда ли?) Мне, в отличие от вас, только шестнадцать с полоничонкой годиков.

Comment: Переполненный даже!  Ведь это не только, а УЖЕ шестнадцать годочков.   Так много! Но здесь интересный синтаксис, хотелось бы его точнее определить. I like precision, you know, sir.  Перечисление? No, a mini-cat. Здесь же нет запятых.  Это предложный  оборот со значением наименования, вроде бы препозитивный номинатив. https://web.archive.org/web/20211127220246/http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-025.htm